# How to get reference to `NSPersistentCloudKitContainer` when using SwiftData with CloudKit

Tags: swift-data

`SwiftData` with `CloudKit` is using/ build on top of `NSPersistentCloudKitContainer`.
One can observe `.import` & `.export` events by listing to `NSPersistentCloudKitContainer.eventChangedNotification`.

In order to fetch a list of the past events from `NSPersistentCloudKitContainer` a reference to the container is required.

Is there any way I can get this reference from `SwiftData`, e.g. through the `ModelContainer` or `MainContext`?